# iSight Camera in iPhone 5 , 5s, 5c: Is the image resolution 3264 x 2448 or 3284 x 2448?

Tags: iphone, webcam

Apple said iPhone 5, 5s, 5c has 8MP iSight camera.

A website says

```
iSight of 5c & 5s: 3264 x 2448 Pixels  (7.99 MP)
http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/comparison/157b258a
http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/model/70af28ac

iSight of iPhone 5: 3284 x 2448 Pixels (8.4 MP)
http://www.devicespecifications.com/en/comparison/aba74df9
```

Don't the iSight of 5, 5c, 5s have the same resolution? Something seems inaccurate here. So what is the exact number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iPhone 5 spec given is [definitely wrong](http://www.digitalcameraworld.com/2012/09/13/iphone-5-camera-whats-in-it-for-photographers/) ([2](http://www.engadget.com/2012/09/12/apple-details-iphone-5s-new-camera-8mp-same-as-iphone-4s-but/)) and the 3 have the same resolution :  3284 * 2448 => 8.4 Mpx.

Comment: Just a typo correction required in the answer. The resolution is 3264 x 2448 (not 3284). Source: http://www.anandtech.com/show/7329/some-thoughts-about-the-iphone-5s-camera-improvements

Comment: so there is no such 3284 x 2448 Pixels existed?

Comment: Yep. There is no such that.